# "Stick" an svg to the top of an element as it's resizing

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to add a stylish "wave" element to the top of a div, however with my attempts, the svg moves from its position and leaves a gap when the browser resizes.

[image]

Here's a mockup of what it should look like:

[image]

CSS:

```
.wave {
  position: absolute;
  top: -72px;
}

.container {
  background: #eee;
}

.col-1 {
  height: 200px;
}

.col-2 {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

My other attempt was using `background-image: url(wave.svg);` in a `:after` selector, but same results.

Here's a codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmRyLK

How can I get the wave to keep put as is when it's resizing and when it's not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your SVG as a background image on the element where you have your funky purple bit, you can stack the background images on each other, like so:

```
.purpleElement{
    background: url("/path/to/asset/image.svg") bottom center no-repeat, purple;
    background-size: 100%;

    /*I've set a height here to replicate content*/
    height: 70vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[I've forked off your codepen to show what will happen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvROyK)

Comment: Hi, your link is broken.

Comment: So this works if `background-size` is set to `110%`, but I still see a "line" appear when resizing.

Comment: Ah how embarrassing, that's fixed now. Out of curiosity which browser are you using? I've personally had a bit of trouble with FF not behaving nicely with things like these.

Comment: Chrome. I'm also using bootstrap which may have some styling that's causing that issue.